# Connecting to Server on remote through port fails due to dynamic random port

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, tcp

I am trying to connect to a supercomputer through ssh and port forwarding.

The application is a C++ both server and client.

Here is the port data :

```
// default values
server_address = "localhost";
port = 12346;
```

I connect to the server with the following :

```
ssh -Y <adress> -L12346:localhost:12346 -l <username>
```

(also tried)

```
ssh -Y <adress> -L12346:127.0.0.1:12346 -l <username>
```

My application start on the server with this log message :

```
INFO:  startServer: Port 12346 on server <SERVERNAME> opened and waits client.
```

Everything is fine until here.

But when I try connecting with the the other computer, the server refuses with the following log:

```
debug1: Connection to port 12346 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 12346 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 12346 for 127.0.0.1 port 12346, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 45446 to 127.0.0.1 port 12346, nchannels 4
```

The port here (45446) is something I havent set and it is dynamic, so always changing.

The application(server-client connection) works perfectly when I run both of them on my desktop.

Any recommendation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The port `45446` is the port where your application is running and it is always random. It should not bother you.

What should bother you is the reason why the connection was refused on the line above. This means that the ssh is trying to connect to the port 123456 and the connection was not successful. This can be affected either by the server configuration (`PermitOpen`) or something on the server, which is hard to guess from this limited information.

Comment: From the client side, do you think there is anything to do ? It is a scientific networks supercomputer, and I try always port while I am in the network. Any suggestions is highly appreciated.